# why this c program output 4?

Tags: c, puzzle

why this program output 4

```
#define SIZE 10
void size(int arr[SIZE])
{
   printf("size of array is:%d\n",sizeof(arr));
}

 int main()
{
      int arr[SIZE];
      size(arr);
      return 0;
}
```

what hanppen when  call `size(arr`) in `main` function, does mean that assign the address `arr` in the `main` function to `arr[SIZE]` in the `size` function?

can someone  interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `arr` is a pointer. A pointer takes 4 bytes. `sizeof` returns the size of the variable passed as argument (in byte). That's why.